# Erro ao buscar a description em outra tabela relacionada

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Erro:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

View

```
@foreach ($titulos as $titulo)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $titulo->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $titulo->titulo_tipos->description }}</td> //ERRO NESSA LINHA
        <td>{{ $titulo->cliente->nome }}</td>
        <td>{{ $titulo->devedor->nome }}</td>
        <td>{{ $titulo->Valor }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Models Titulo

```
class Titulo extends Model
{
     public function titulo_tipos()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\TituloTipo');
     }
}
```

Model Titulo Tipo

```
class TituloTipo extends Model
{
    public function titulo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Titulo');
    }
}
```

Migration

```
Schema::create('titulos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->integer('tipo_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('tipo_id')->references('id')->on('titulo_tipos');

    $table->integer('cliente_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('cliente_id')->references('id')->on('clientes');

    $table->integer('devedor_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('devedor_id')->references('id')->on('devedors');

    $table->date('vencimento_titulo')->nullable();
    $table->string('status')->default('pendente');
    $table->decimal('Valor')->nullable();

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Na Model de Titulos referencie a foreign key tipo_id      
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\TituloTipo', 'tipo_id');

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu erro está em

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\TituloTipo');
```

Ao usar o `belongsTo` com apenas um parâmetro você assume que a foreign key será o nome da model relacionada acompanhada de _id, no caso titulotipo_id, mas esse campo não existe em sua model. Você tem que referenciar então, manualmente, qual seria o campo foreignkey que fará referência a tabela de TituloTipo. Aplicando a correção ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
$this->belongsTo('App\Models\TituloTipo', 'tipo_id');
```

Essa e outras explicações você pode encontrar na [Documentação do Laravel.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)